# How can I attach multiple pictures to an email?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.1

How can I attach more than one picture to an email using the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Just call `-addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` multiple times.